# how to access a property of a state hook that´s not initialized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I safely use an object in a component if the state is not set yet?
I initialize it as null (I could use {} but that causes other effects). I get:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
someService(user => setUser(user))
const someRef = useRef(null);

if (!user) {
    // to avoid the undefined user.name I tried this but it causes an issue with useRef (because the actual someRef is not rendered when !user
    return <p>loading user</p>
}

return (
    <div>
        <p>{user.name}</p>
        <div ref={someRef}>hello</div>
    </div>
)
```

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-dust-y2z5k?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

at this point the user is not created and we should render the "loading user" this is fine but someRef is causing issues because there are messages but the component is not rendered. uncomment line 5 and comment line 6 to see it working

Comment: This seems like it should work, assuming `render` is a typo of `return`. Please provide a [mcve] that shows the problem and your `user` object that you're trying to get `name` on.

Comment: Sorry about that. removed a lot of code to illustrate the error and that happened. I updated the example. doing what I´m doing is causing issues with useRef

Comment: Your code looks invalid. Can't have two HTML node children returned. Please show the actual code you're running. Also, I don't see what the ref has to do with an undef property `name` on `user`.

Comment: done. I changed it now sorry

Comment: Thanks but it's unclear what to make of this, still. Where/what is the error with `useRef`? Please read the [mcve] link. If we can't reproduce the problem, there's no way to help.

Comment: done! reprex added!

Comment: It should be in the question itself, but anyway, you're attempting to access `style` on a null reference. That won't work. It's not clear what you want to achieve, but you could wrap that in a condition (`if (user.current) { access the .style property on user.current }`).

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
someService(user => setUser(user))

render(){
    return({user? <p>{user.name}</p> :<p>loading user</p>});
}
```

You can use `useEffect` on ref and user change to set another variable so:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Test() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const someRef = useRef(null);
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user && someRef) {
            setLoaded(true)
        }
    }, [user, someRef])

    return (
        loaded ?
            <div>
                <p>{user.name}</p>
                <div ref={someRef}>hello</div>
            </div> : <div>not loaded yet</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: hello. yes that was my first approach but that caused an issue with a useRef I have (question updated)